Add "trend" like line to graphs
Below, you can find whole data.frame as I think it is the only proper way to test your potential code.
structure(list(Days = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
                        11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
                        24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
                        37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
                        50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 
                        63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 
                        76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 
                        89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
                        7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
                        20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
                        33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
                        46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
                        59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 
                        72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 
                        85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 1L, 
                        2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
                        16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
                        29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
                        42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 
                        55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
                        68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
                        81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
                        94L, 95L, 96L), PG_Nr = c(1757, 1997, 2293, 2498, 2729, 2930, 
                                                  3121, 3222, 3320, 3426, 3542, 3700, 3774, 3883, 3892, 3954, 4027, 
                                                  4068, 4127, 3926, 3475, 3395, 3488, 3453, 3342, 3264, 3182, 3123, 
                                                  3153, 3159, 3191, 3311, 3159, 3102, 3293, 3605, 3779, 3968, 4038, 
                                                  4171, 4254, 4467, 4497, 4510, 4764, 5028, 5120, 5089, 5021, 5060, 
                                                  5002, 5156, 5192, 5035, 5040, 4931, 4990, 4970, 4929, 4793, 4559, 
                                                  4414, 4263, 4073, 3919, 1103, 1012, 530, 768, 922, 890, 745, 
                                                  642, 647, 667, 1467, 656, 655, 693, 708, 760, 852, 823, 799, 
                                                  884, 1001, 380, 1067, 1325, 560, 697, 770, 859, 1020, 1129, 1049, 
                                                  99, 132, 160, 194, 209, 215, 259, 246, 316, 298, 248, 541, 393, 
                                                  401, 435, 625, 685, 629, 657, 662, 679, 694, 62, 933, 1010, 1063, 
                                                  1101, 1170, 1239, 1288, 1419, 1493, 1467, 61, 1742, 1947, 2130, 
                                                  2255, 2407, 2582, 2702, 2832, 2856, 2843, 47, 2993, 3217, 3328, 
                                                  3321, 3399, 3645, 3806, 3922, 3971, 3845, 29, 3809, 4144, 4252, 
                                                  4331, 4387, 4288, 4252, 4329, 4367, 4203, 32, 4018, 4201, 4192, 
                                                  4116, 4355, 4267, 4489, 4575, 4569, 4525, 250, 4447, 4574, 4793, 
                                                  4822, 4790, 4766, 4709, 4570, 4913, 4945, 4831, 4650, 4623, 4503, 
                                                  3529, 3437, 3260, 113, 1080, 1286, 1393, 1522, 1587, 1644, 1656, 
                                                  1729, 1740, 1712, 532, 1486, 1790, 1997, 2074, 2136, 2277, 2373, 
                                                  2374, 2333, 2251, 452, 1990, 2188, 2328, 2247, 2410, 2457, 2524, 
                                                  2590, 2574, 2412, 551, 2271, 2409, 2464, 2602, 2619, 2706, 2779, 
                                                  2785, 2712, 2123, 516, 2398, 2547, 2730, 2750, 2662, 2534, 2518, 
                                                  2510, 2441, 2230, 560, 2267, 2210, 2208, 1977, 2113, 2104, 1998, 
                                                  2001, 2034, 1906, 601, 1578, 2386, 2281, 2104, 2037, 2016, 2017, 
                                                  1300, 934, 1005, 634, 1869, 1965, 2179, 2201, 2146, 2224, 2167, 
                                                  2042, 2137, 1672, 721, 1093, 819, 304, 299, 190, 213, 372, 833
                        ), Name = c("Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", 
                                    "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", 
                                    "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Tim", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", 
                                    "Greg", "Greg", "Greg", "Greg")), row.names = c("Days.1", "Days.2", 
                                                                                    "Days.3", "Days.4", "Days.5", "Days.6", "Days.7", "Days.8", "Days.9", 
                                                                                    "Days.10", "Days.11", "Days.12", "Days.13", "Days.14", "Days.15", 
                                                                                    "Days.16", "Days.17", "Days.18", "Days.19", "Days.20", "Days.21", 
                                                                                    "Days.22", "Days.23", "Days.24", "Days.25", "Days.26", "Days.27", 
                                                                                    "Days.28", "Days.29", "Days.30", "Days.31", "Days.32", "Days.33", 
                                                                                    "Days.34", "Days.35", "Days.36", "Days.37", "Days.38", "Days.39", 
                                                                                    "Days.40", "Days.41", "Days.42", "Days.43", "Days.44", "Days.45", 
                                                                                    "Days.46", "Days.47", "Days.48", "Days.49", "Days.50", "Days.51", 
                                                                                    "Days.52", "Days.53", "Days.54", "Days.55", "Days.56", "Days.57", 
                                                                                    "Days.58", "Days.59", "Days.60", "Days.61", "Days.62", "Days.63", 
                                                                                    "Days.64", "Days.65", "Days.66", "Days.67", "Days.68", "Days.69", 
                                                                                    "Days.70", "Days.71", "Days.72", "Days.73", "Days.74", "Days.75", 
                                                                                    "Days.76", "Days.77", "Days.78", "Days.79", "Days.80", "Days.81", 
                                                                                    "Days.82", "Days.83", "Days.84", "Days.85", "Days.86", "Days.87", 
                                                                                    "Days.88", "Days.89", "Days.90", "Days.91", "Days.92", "Days.93", 
                                                                                    "Days.94", "Days.95", "Days.96", "Days.110", "Days.210", "Days.310", 
                                                                                    "Days.410", "Days.510", "Days.610", "Days.710", "Days.810", "Days.97", 
                                                                                    "Days.101", "Days.111", "Days.121", "Days.131", "Days.141", "Days.151", 
                                                                                    "Days.161", "Days.171", "Days.181", "Days.191", "Days.201", "Days.211", 
                                                                                    "Days.221", "Days.231", "Days.241", "Days.251", "Days.261", "Days.271", 
                                                                                    "Days.281", "Days.291", "Days.301", "Days.311", "Days.321", "Days.331", 
                                                                                    "Days.341", "Days.351", "Days.361", "Days.371", "Days.381", "Days.391", 
                                                                                    "Days.401", "Days.411", "Days.421", "Days.431", "Days.441", "Days.451", 
                                                                                    "Days.461", "Days.471", "Days.481", "Days.491", "Days.501", "Days.511", 
                                                                                    "Days.521", "Days.531", "Days.541", "Days.551", "Days.561", "Days.571", 
                                                                                    "Days.581", "Days.591", "Days.601", "Days.611", "Days.621", "Days.631", 
                                                                                    "Days.641", "Days.651", "Days.661", "Days.671", "Days.681", "Days.691", 
                                                                                    "Days.701", "Days.711", "Days.721", "Days.731", "Days.741", "Days.751", 
                                                                                    "Days.761", "Days.771", "Days.781", "Days.791", "Days.801", "Days.811", 
                                                                                    "Days.821", "Days.831", "Days.841", "Days.851", "Days.861", "Days.871", 
                                                                                    "Days.881", "Days.891", "Days.901", "Days.911", "Days.921", "Days.931", 
                                                                                    "Days.941", "Days.951", "Days.961", "Days.112", "Days.212", "Days.312", 
                                                                                    "Days.412", "Days.512", "Days.612", "Days.712", "Days.812", "Days.98", 
                                                                                    "Days.102", "Days.113", "Days.122", "Days.132", "Days.142", "Days.152", 
                                                                                    "Days.162", "Days.172", "Days.182", "Days.192", "Days.202", "Days.213", 
                                                                                    "Days.222", "Days.232", "Days.242", "Days.252", "Days.262", "Days.272", 
                                                                                    "Days.282", "Days.292", "Days.302", "Days.313", "Days.322", "Days.332", 
                                                                                    "Days.342", "Days.352", "Days.362", "Days.372", "Days.382", "Days.392", 
                                                                                    "Days.402", "Days.413", "Days.422", "Days.432", "Days.442", "Days.452", 
                                                                                    "Days.462", "Days.472", "Days.482", "Days.492", "Days.502", "Days.513", 
                                                                                    "Days.522", "Days.532", "Days.542", "Days.552", "Days.562", "Days.572", 
                                                                                    "Days.582", "Days.592", "Days.602", "Days.613", "Days.622", "Days.632", 
                                                                                    "Days.642", "Days.652", "Days.662", "Days.672", "Days.682", "Days.692", 
                                                                                    "Days.702", "Days.713", "Days.722", "Days.732", "Days.742", "Days.752", 
                                                                                    "Days.762", "Days.772", "Days.782", "Days.792", "Days.802", "Days.813", 
                                                                                    "Days.822", "Days.832", "Days.842", "Days.852", "Days.862", "Days.872", 
                                                                                    "Days.882", "Days.892", "Days.902", "Days.912", "Days.922", "Days.932", 
                                                                                    "Days.942", "Days.952", "Days.962"), class = "data.frame")

That's a code I use to generate ggplot. I would like to add a line to these dots, however based on my "own" rules.
ggplot(data = data, aes(x=Days, y=PG_Nr)) + geom_point(aes(colour=Name))

It produces a plot like that:

And I would like to add a line like I did manually for Tim. It's not a proper one but I am expecting this kind of trend. The most important for me is to keep all dots but somehow ignore those which you can clearly see are outliers. I do not know if applying a rule that results has to be in range of percentage of last Days and following Days is the best solution but I am open for your propositions.

I had to remove one guy from data.frame as it was exceeding the allowed space. So examples are different..

Have you tried using geom_smooth()?

No, I have not. I have never tried this function. Can you briefly show me how to apply it to my plot ? In meantime I will read (help) about this function and find its potential best application for my plots.

Does geom_smooth provide the line you want?
The other way to do this would be to use a rolling average. See added example for Tom.
Here is a simple version with default geom_smooth() parameters using method = 'loess' and formula = 'y ~ x', you can adjust the parameters to get a closer fit.
df1 is name I have given your data frame from the question.


library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(Days, PG_Nr, colour = Name)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth()





Rolling average example:

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

# create data frame for Tom with rolling average data
df_tom <- 
  df1 |> 
  mutate(days_ra = rollmean(PG_Nr, 8, fill = NA), 
         days_ra = ifelse(is.na(days_ra), Days, days_ra),
         .by = Name) |> 
  filter(Name == "Tom")

# separate data frame for Tim and Greg
df_tg <- 
  df1 |> 
  filter(Name %in% c("Tim", "Greg"))  

# plot
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df_tg, mapping = aes(Days, PG_Nr, colour = Name))+
  geom_smooth(data = df_tg, mapping = aes(Days, PG_Nr, colour = Name)) +
  geom_point(data = df_tom, mapping = aes(Days, PG_Nr, colour = Name)) +
  geom_line(data = df_tom, mapping = aes(Days, days_ra, colour = Name)) +
  ggtitle("Trend line for Tom using rolling average function `zoo::rollmean()`")


Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.0.2

I like it very much for Tim and Greg but for Tom I would like it to start smoothing from the first Day already and also it does not do such a good fit like for two other guys.

See additional approach using rolling average. There may be a simpler way to achieve this but I think this sets out the steps clearly.

You might be looking for a rolling average that ignores outliers? Here is one way to do that:
1. Create a function to get the mean of data points whilst ignoring outliers:
Here, we will pass the whole sample to our function and use the standard deviation of the sample to determine which data points count as an outlier.
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

clean_mean <- function(x, sample){
  sample_sd <- sd(sample)
  x_mean <- mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
  mean(x[x > x_mean - 0.5 * sample_sd & x < x_mean + 0.5 * sample_sd])
}

2. Create a rolling mean that ignores outliers
We can create a rolling_average() function that gets n values surrounding each data point and averages them - making sure to use our clean_mean() function to get averages in which outliers are ignored.
rolling_average <- function(x, n){

  # Get half of n rounded down
  half_n <- 1:floor(n/2)
  
  lag <- 
    map(half_n, \(y) lag(x, y)) |> 
    reduce(cbind)
  
  lead <-
    map(half_n, \(y) lead(x, y)) |> 
    reduce(cbind)
  
  cbind(lead, x, lag) |> 
    apply(1, \(y) clean_mean(y, sample = x))
}

3. Add the column and plot
We can perform a grouped mutate() to get rolling averages for each Name. Then by passing a different y aesthetic to each geom_* function we can overlay our points with a line geom that shows the rolling mean.
We're using n = 5 for our rolling mean, but you can increase this value for a smoother line.
data |>
  mutate(avg = rolling_average(PG_Nr, 5), .by = Name) |> 
  ggplot(aes(colour = Name, x = Days)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = PG_Nr)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = avg))
#> Warning: Removed 12 rows containing missing values or values outside the scale range
#> (`geom_line()`).


Created on 2024-06-11 with reprex v2.1.0
